# JSON parsing and assigning to objects problems in C#

Tags: c#, json

```
    private newsArticle[] RetrieveNews(string url)
    {
        newsArticle[] r = null;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(newsArticle[]));
            r = (newsArticle[])jsonSerializer.ReadObject(
                new MemoryStream(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                        new StreamReader(
                            response.GetResponseStream()
                        ).ReadToEnd()
                    )
                )
            );
        }

        return r;
    }
```

So I have a function like this which retrieves values from an api and deserializes them into the class stated below.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class newsArticle
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "message")]
        public string message { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "image")]
        public string image { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "published")]
        public bool published { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "created_at")]
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "updated_at")]
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "publisher")]
        public string publisher { get; set; }
    }
```

The above is the class to which the values are getting deserialized onto.
Now time to call the method mentioned at the very top.

```
    private void launcher_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newsArticle[] articles = RetrieveNews("https://alsage.multisol.eu/api/v1/news");
        articles.Initialize();

    }
```

So I retrieve the news feed in form of json.
Now I have to take the value of the string from the class, in this example the string "message" and assign its value to a textbox so that I can view the news in C#. I am unable to retrieve the string "mesage" from the class.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain what you mean by "I am unable". Any error messages? Or unexpected results (then please show sample input data, expected results and the result you got instead).

Comment: There is no result as I want to know how to retrieve the custom string from the array. If I can't retrieve a string from the array, how would I show a result, leave alone posting it here.

Comment: Calling `articles.Initialize()` sets all array elements back to `null`, so all data already parsed is lost again. To access the `message` property of an element in the array, simply access `articles[index].message` where `index` is, well, the index of the element you want to have. I don't understand the question, is this about basic c# "how to access an array element" or "how to access a property of an instance of a class"?

Comment: Both. Hope your answers work.